# Numpy.save text | Combine current date with specific file name as txt title

Tags: python, numpy, datetime

To store the result of calculations, I save them in txt files using

```
np.savetxt('filename.txt', ..).
```

What I would like to do is including the current time in the filename so that the file is called "year-month-day filename.txt".

I tried to create a string variable and to use the package datetime to get the date in the way I need it. However I was not able to concatenate the date with the specific filename in the `np.savetxt()` function.

I am not really familiar yet with numpy so I am looking forward for help!

Thank you for advice

Comment: use `strftime` from the `datetime` module's `datetime` class, e.g. `(datetime.strftime(datetime.utcnow(), '%Y-%m-%d') + ' filename.txt')`. Modify the format string as you wish, and leave the "utc" to get the local time (date) of your machine.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple, try with this:

```
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np

x = y = z = np.arange(0.0,5.0,1.0)
time_now = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")
np.savetxt(time_now+'_project.txt', (x,y,z))
```

If you want another format only you can modify the strftime parameter, that works for me. Enjoy your day.